Looping Range Invalid array
In this challenge, you will build a function that creates an array for a given start, end, and step parameter.

The function takes three integer parameters: start, end, and step.
The function should return an array of numbers from start to end, counting by step.

The function checks for incorrect parameters by ensuring that;

start, end, or step are defined
start is not greater than end
step is greater than zero
If any of these parameters are not met, the function should return an empty array [].

My code:


function range (start, end, step) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(range(0, 10, 2));



RangeError: Invalid array length

what if step is 0 or a negative number?

What's the expected array length? What parameters are you passing to your function?

I don't see where are you validating whether start is greater than end

Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. What's your question?

This is the example: range(0, 10, 2); Output: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]. The start of 0, end in 10, and steps by 2.

@jabaa - why am I getting a RangeError: Invalid array length

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_array_length

Can you add [mcve] as runnable code to your question? I guess, the arguments are the problem. The given code works as described.

You gave a working example, what data are you using when you get the error?

Nothing in your code is checking the array length; where is that coming from?

Okay, so the problem is that the 'step' returns empty when negative.

You forgot to do the validations described.
While doing the validations, you can use early return to get a code with more readability.

start, end, or step are defined

if (start === undefined || end === undefined || step === undefined) {
  return []
}


start is not greater than end

if (start > end) {
  return []
}


step is greater than zero

if (step <= 0) {
  return []
}

Final function:
function range (start, end, step) {
  if (start === undefined || end === undefined || step === undefined) {
    return []
  }

  if (start > end) {
    return []
  }

  if (step <= 0) {
    return []
  }

  const result = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
    result.push(i);
  }
  return result;
}

